how we can handle the navigation between screen when we create react native librerary in react native
When creating a library with npx create-react-native-library@latest (using the bridge-guide option), the library does not include a MainActivity because it is designed to be modular and integrated into host applications rather than functioning as a standalone app. Navigation within the library's screens can still be achieved, but it requires a different approach. your text
